# auto prefix in url

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am using language prefix in my app:

```
Router::connect('/:language/:controller/:action/*',
                       array(),
                       array('language' => '[a-z]{3}'));
```

When I use `$this->Html->link('title',$url_array)` I have to set the language prefix manually.
And what I want is when the prefix is present in current url then when I use `->link(...)` it should add this prefix automaticly to url. Only when I set this prefix explicite then it should be different.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to manage your locale application wide (not per user) you should check what the current locale setting is in the URL in your AppController's beforeFilter(). The :language prefix in your `Router` will ensure that you provide unique URLs for differently localized content.

`$this->Html->link()` will act as you expect if the Config.language configuration setting is managed in the right manner.

So in your `AppController::beforeFilter()` make an if() statement to detect which locale is being requested and depending on that do:

```
Configure::write('Config.language', 'fre');
```

or

```
Configure::write('Config.language', 'eng');
```

Doing this will ensure that both I18n and [TranslateBehavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/translate.html) access the same language value.

If you would like to manage application locale per user you can store the current locale in the Session:

```
class AppController extends Controller {
    public function beforeFilter() {
        Configure::write('Config.language', $this->Session->read('Config.language'));
    }
}
```

Of course you should also use the [Translation Function __()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/global-constants-and-functions.html#__). Check out the [Internationalization and Localization](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html) section of the Cake Book.
Oh yeah, there is also something very important which is mentioned in the "fine print" of that article:

> There’s one other aspect of localizing your application which is not covered by the use of the translate functions, and that is date/money formats. Don’t forget that CakePHP is PHP :), therefore to set the formats for these things you need to use setlocale. 
>   If you pass a locale that doesn’t exist on your computer to setlocale it will have no effect. You can find the list of available locales by running the command `locale -a` in a terminal.